# getSceneList does not work

Tags: python, scene

I'm trying to get a list of scenes in my .blend file.

```
bpy.ops.logic.getSceneList()
```

works once, but the second call throws an error that I don't understand.

```
    scenes = {sc.name: sc for sc in bpy.ops.logic.getSceneList()}


  File "/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.logic.getSceneList" error, could not be found
```

Can anyone jump in and help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this for the game engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood how blender python works. Should have used BGE (Blender game engine)